# react-skeleton-loader-pulse dependent on prismjs which is vulnerable

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, audit, react-loading-skeleton

I want to audit fix my dependencies, I have following vulnerability.

prismjs  <=1.26.0
Severity: high
Cross-Site Scripting in Prism - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wvhm-4hhf-97x9
prismjs Regular Expression Denial of Service vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hqhp-5p83-hx96
Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) in Prism - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-gj77-59wh-66hg
Denial of service in prismjs - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-h4hr-7fg3-h35w
Cross-site Scripting in Prism - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-3949-f494-cm99
No fix available
node_modules/refractor/node_modules/prismjs
refractor  <=3.4.0 || 4.0.0 - 4.1.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of prismjs
node_modules/refractor

I tried updating react-skeleton-loader-pulse but it is already on latest 1.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the package with react-loading-skeleton and remove react-skeleton-loader-pulse.